# mp4 stream to iphone/ipod touch via http

Tags: iphone

is it possible to stream video to iphone/ipod touch over http without a proper streaming server with .net? may be some sort of progressive download?

Comment: i should have said video instead of mp4

Comment: Does this looks promising for your needs? www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1916-how-play-mp3-audio-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I suggest is to use HTML 5. The iDevices (iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad) doesn't support Silverlight or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mobile devices you are trying to watch the videos from have a 'video size limit' because when i test my website i test everything over wifi for real world scenarios and when i reach a certain video size i am not able to watch the video on that mobile device. videos under 1gb work great, but when i try watching a 2.5gb HD video it will not open the video on my ipod/ipad/iphone/android devices....